# Is there a way to unify the numbering of tables caption in r markdown to html in r via `kable()` and `htmltable()`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

When I want to print some tables in html report from `knitr`, sometime I use `knitr::kable()`, and other times I use `htmltable::htmltable`.

When I use `bookdown::html_document2` in the `YAML` numbering of tables from `kable` is automatic. However, it is not for `htmltable`, and I need to use `options(table_counter = TRUE)`, which generates another numbering mechanism. Is there a way to unify it?

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Guilherme"
date: "10/26/2020"
output:   
  bookdown::html_document2
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(table_counter = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(mtcars[1:5,1:5],
          caption = "XX")
```

```{r}
htmlTable(mtcars[1:5,1:5],
          caption = "XX")
```

```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars[1:5,1:5],
          caption = "XX")
```
````

Outputs:

[image]

Thanks!